# H2 database CSVREAD is not trimming quotes

Tags: csv, h2, delimiter, quote

My input file has quotes around each field.

```
"1386568706","1","","","","DK","ME","LY PRECRT","","","A.D."
```

I want to read these fields using CSVREAD. I tried following options.

```
insert into s_no_date
select convert(PI,bigint),
convert(ENT_CODE,int),
REPLACEMENT_PI,
EMN,
PNAME,
d,
er,
ert,
sd,
cg,
sdf
','fieldDelimiter=')
```

I am getting following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""1578956447""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:578)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:942)
```

Another option tried:

```
insert into s_no_date
select convert(PI,bigint),
convert(ENT_CODE,int),
REPLACEMENT_PI,
EMN,
PNAME,
d,
er,
ert,
sd,
cg,
sdf
')
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:940)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is what worked. I also had to change data type of ENT_CODE to varchar from int as it can be nullable. I had to escape quote as fieldDelimiter

```
insert into s_no_date
select convert(PI,bigint),
ENT_CODE,
REPLACEMENT_PI,
EMN,
PNAME,
d,
er,
ert,
sd,
cg,
sdf
','fieldDelimiter=\"');
```